# How two consecutive yield statement work in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, yield

I stumble upon this code from [pymotw.com](https://pymotw.com/3/itertools/) in merging and splitting section.

```
from itertools import *


def make_iterables_to_chain():
    yield [1, 2, 3]
    yield ['a', 'b', 'c']


for i in chain.from_iterable(make_iterables_to_chain()):
    print(i, end=' ')
print()
```

I can not understand how make_iterables_to_chain() is working. It contains two yield statement, how does it work?
I know how generators work but there but there was only single **yield** statement.

Help, please!

Comment: There probably was only one yield statement, but was it not in a loop?

Comment: there are two. I just didn't understand the fundamental of two yield. I thought once yield is encountered it does not go to other yield, but that is not the case.

Comment: The canonical question for this has hundreds of links, millions of views and is the single most upvoted question in the Python tag. The first example given in the question uses two `yield` statements, so that can't be an objection (even though the logical application is straightforward anyway). It's mystifying to me that nobody noticed such an obvious duplicate closure at the time, let alone letting it sit around for 5 years.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The same way a single `yield` works.

You can have as many `yield`s as you like in a generator, when `__next__` is called on it, it will execute until it bumps into the next yield. You then get back the yielded expression and the generator pauses until it's `__next__` method is invoked again.

Run a couple of `next` calls on the generator to see this:

```
>>> g = make_iterables_to_chain()  # get generator
>>> next(g) # start generator, go to first yield, get result
[1, 2, 3]
>>> next(g) # resume generator, go to second yield, get result
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> # next(g) raises Exception since no more yields are found
```

Answer (score 5):

A generator effectively allows a function to return **multiple times**. Every time a `yield` statement is executed, the value is returned to the caller, and the caller can continue the function's execution.

Usually, they are used as iterables in `for` loops.

The following function increments every element in an iterable by an amount:

```python3
def inc_each(nums, inc):
    for i in nums:
        yield i + inc
```

Here is an example of the usage:

```python3
gen = inc_each([1, 2, 3, 4], 100)
print(list(gen)) # [101, 102, 103, 104]
```

`list` is used here to convert an arbitrary iterable (in this case a generator) to a list.

The function you describe executes two yield statements:

```python3
def make_iterables_to_chain():
    yield [1, 2, 3]
    yield ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

If you call it, it returns a generator that, if iterated through, yields the lists `[1, 2, 3]` and `['a', 'b', 'c']`.

```python3
gen = make_iterables_to_chain()
print(list(gen)) # [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

`itertools.chain.from_iterable` will take a (possibly infinite) iterable of iterables and "flatten" it, returning a (possible infinite) iterable as the result.

Here is a way it could be implemented:

```python3
def from_iterable(iterables):
    for iterable in iterables:
        for i in iterable:
            yield i
```

Comment: do you mean that when first time make_iterables_to_chain() is called it gives the first yield statement i.e. [1,2,3] and when second time it is called the second yield statement is called i.e. ['a', 'b', 'c']

Comment: @ispeedster Generator expressions actually have an additional layer of indirection. When you call `make_iterables_to_chain`, it returns a *generator object* that can be iterated through using `iter()` and `next()` (though this is usually handled automatically by `for` loops). So the function itself is only ever called once, but the resulting object can be iterated through and can yield multiple values.

Answer (score -1):

Just adding on top of the previous answers that when using such code:

```
def my_yield_function():
  yield 1
  yield 'test'
  yield 2
  yield true
```

You can unpack all the value with such code:

```
w,x,y,z = my_yield_function()
```